# How to avoid retrieve unwanted data that consumes extra time

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have these three models A , B , C .

Assume these classes look like :

```
Public class A 
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public ICollection<B> bc {get;set;} 
    public ICollection<C> cc {get;set} 
}

Public class B 
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

Public class C  
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Suppose I want all data from A except cc or bc .

The problem is whenever I call getall method, it returns everything related, actually it's much more complicated in my code so there are also collections in B and C which brings pretty much every thing and it takes a lot of time to execute,it's like a loop.

So far, I have tried using select but still go to the model and fetch all fields.

Any help Please , and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Data Annotations to exclude a property from the model. You can visit this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/included-properties to refer more. Hope to help and Happy new year, my friend :))

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public DateTime LoadedFromDatabase { get; set; }
}

class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .Ignore(b => b.LoadedFromDatabase);
    }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public DateTime LoadedFromDatabase { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thank u and happy new year.
that's great but in some places in my code i may need all data , so this will not work in that cases

Comment: @michael: In your case, I think you can use Automapper. Sorry for the late response, my friend :))

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may not be using `.Select` correctly, because this is precisely what it is designed to do.

To get relevant A details, without B's or C's:

```
var aDetails = context.As.Select(a => new { a.Id, a.Name }).ToList();
```

Note that this returns an anonymous type containing just the fields you want, in this case, the ID and name from the A records.  Now if you want to return that data to be used in a view etc. then you can define a view model class to called AViewModel for example with that ID and Name:

```
var viewModels = context.As.Select(a => new AViewModel{ Id = a.Id, Name = a.Name }).ToList();
```

Often people get caught out by attempting to send entities to a view. This is a bad, bad pattern which is too often glazed over in the sake of avoiding defining another POCO class that looks a lot like the entity. However there are 2 really good reasons you should avoid it: The security of information, and performance. (Outlined [here](https://py-sty.blogspot.com/2018/12/2-very-good-reasons-why-you-should.html)) If you do something like:

```
var results = context.As.ToList();
```

or even

```
var results = context.As.Select(a => a).ToList();
```

With LazyLoading enabled (EF6) This will load just your A records without the B's or C's. However, if you attempt to pass those entities back to your client, the serializer will iterate over every property, tripping the lazy-loads on the B and C collections, loading each set for each individual A record. When returning a collection of A's, this will be far, far worse than if you had eager-loaded the Bs and Cs in your query because if you return 5x A records, the lazy load calls will amount to:

SELECT FROM B WHERE AId = 1, SELECT FROM B WHERE AId = 2, ...

SELECT FROM C WHERE AId = 1, SELECT FROM C WHERE AId = 2, ...

10x extra SQL statements instead of including all related B and C rows in the one initial (bigger) SQL statement. You can avoid this performance trap by turning off EF lazy loading (turning off proxies) but then you will be left with empty collections which do not reflect your actual data state. (IMO an entity should always completely represent it's data state, no guessing whether missing data simply wasn't loaded, or the entity actually has no related data.)

To expand on how `Select` can improve performance; Lets say you have a set of orders which have a list of order items, and each order is associated to a customer. You want the order #, the total cost of the order items, and the customer name. You don't want to load all order items and customer details for every order:

```
var orderDetails = context.Orders
    .Where(o => o.OrderDate >= startDate && o.OrderDate < endDate)
    .Select(o => new OrderViewModel
    {
        OrderId = o.OrderId,
        OrderNumber = o.OrderNumber,
        CustomerName = o.Customer.FullName,
        Total = o.OrderLines.Sum(ol => ol.UnitPrice * ol.Quantity)
    }).ToList();
```

This is a powerful feature of EF and Linq which helps ensure that the database does most of the work and only returns the fields that you will need. Less data over the wire, less memory use on the app server & client.